# Customize help command in Spring Shell 3.1.6

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I've built a `spring-shell` application and I'd like to customize the built-in `help` command. Currently it looks like this:

```
shell:>help help
NAME
       help - Display help about available commands

SYNOPSIS
       help --command String[] --help

OPTIONS
       --command or -C String[]
       The command to obtain help for.
       [Optional]

       --help or -h
       help for help
       [Optional]
```

and I'd like to customize it so it looks like this e.g. adding the HELP section.

```
shell:>help help

HELP   email: email@dot.com
       Slack: https://slckchannel

NAME
       help - Display help about available commands

SYNOPSIS
       help --command String[] --help

OPTIONS
       --command or -C String[]
       The command to obtain help for.
       [Optional]

       --help or -h
       help for help
       [Optional]
```

Been googling around but haven't found a solution, anyone has a great idea?

--Andy

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `stg` files under the `templates` directory to my liking and that solved the problem